# Visual Studio Phantom Software expiration warning. Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports, report

I'm using visual studio community 2015.  I have been getting the warning message below:
[image]

I cannot figure out what software is generating the warning message.  I suspected Crystal Reports.  I had installed the free version of Crystal for Visual Studio, and I only get this warning on applications that at one time had a crystal report.  I have since deleted all traces of Crystal from my PC (uninstalled, deleted program files folder, and deleted registry key) but I still get this warning on that application.  If I click OK, visual studio closes completely.  While working in the application that creates the error, if I try to add a report via report wizard (not Crystal reports, just visual studio native), I'm immediately prompted with the warning, and VS closes when I hit OK.
Does anyone recognize this warning?
Thanks.

Comment: In this situation, I would try opening your project on a clean install of Windows.  A VM is great for this purpose.  If it the problem still persists, I would closely examine all your dependencies (references) and remove them one by one until this no longer happens and thus you identify the culprait.

Comment: Good tip.  I copied the project to another PC running the same version of visual studio and it works fine, I do not get the warning message.  I suppose that indicates its a piece of software installed on the first pc...